# Как вывести все оценки по всем предметам?

Tags: python, api

Я пытаюсь вывести все оценки ученика с помощью [NetSсhoolAPI](https://netschoolapi.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/), но этого сделать не получается. Я пробовал сначала создавать словарь, в котором будут храниться названия предметов, а в списке - сами оценки. Но в списках начинают храниться одни и те же оценки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка?

Вот такие оценки должны вывестись:
[image: Вот такие оценки должны вывестись]

Сам код:

```
import asyncio
from netschoolapi import NetSchoolAPI
import datetime


async def get_evaluation():
    ns = NetSchoolAPI('https://net-school.cap.ru/')
    await ns.login(
        '',  # Логин пользователя
        '',  # Пароль пользователя
        511,
    )
    diary = await ns.diary(start=datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), end=datetime.date(2024, 5, 31))
    slovar = {}
    eval_slovar = []
    for i in range(len(diary.schedule)):
        for lesson in diary.schedule[i].lessons:
            slovar[lesson.subject] = eval_slovar
            for assignment in lesson.assignments:
                if assignment.mark:
                    slovar[lesson.subject] = eval_slovar.append(assignment.mark)
    print(slovar)
    await ns.logout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(get_evaluation())
```

Comment: В список добавляете, а очищать, не очищаете

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в команде присвоения

```
slovar[lesson.subject] = eval_slovar.append(assignment.mark)
```

потому что на правой стороне **всегда будет значение `None`!**

Да, метод `.append()` добавляет к списку элемент, **но сам метод возвращает `None`.**

(Так принято в Питоне для методов, которые *изменяют объект на месте*.)

---

*Исправление:*

- Сначала добавите к списку элемент,
- затем этот — уже модифицированный — список присвойте.

Значит, вместо вашей одной команды примените две:

```
eval_slovar.append(assignment.mark)
slovar[lesson.subject] = eval_slovar
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но, к сожалению, не получилось! :( https://ibb.co/4TJZqFG

Comment: Решение оказалось вот таким:     diary = await ns.diary(start=datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), end=datetime.date(2024, 5, 31))
    slovar = {}
    for i in range(len(diary.schedule)):
        for lesson in diary.schedule[i].lessons:
            for assignment in lesson.assignments:
                if assignment.mark:
                    if not slovar.get(lesson.subject):
                        slovar[lesson.subject] = []
                    slovar[lesson.subject].append(assignment.mark)

Comment: @Никита Шкаралевич: *«Но, к сожалению, не получилось!»* — Не получилось, но по крайней мере чуть-чуть помогло. Или нет?